# Jsoup, hashMap data Key value

Tags: java

I have a variable of the hashMap type to send data and I have several repeated Keys and hashMap only send one, how can I send several same keys that I get dynamically?

```
Code:
Map<String,String> postData = new HashMap<>();
postData.put("K1",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K1",  "BBBBB");
postData.put("K1",  "CCCCC");
postData.put("K2",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K3",  "AAAAA");


jsoup.connect
........
.data(postData)
....
```

Only send "K1",  "CCCCC"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add and remove items from a multivalue HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062924/how-do-i-add-and-remove-items-from-a-multivalue-hashmap)

Comment: are you saying that K2 and K3 are not sent because they have the same value as k1? or that BBBBC and CCCCC are not sent? because the later is the definition of map. you will need to have a map between string and a collection of string, not string to a single string

Comment: If you want use map to store more value with the same key，try google guava `Multimap`

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` by design only allows one value for the same key, and it overrides it whenever you re-set the same key. What you are looking for is a MultiValueMap. Check this thread: [How do I add and remove items from a multivalue HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062924/how-do-i-add-and-remove-items-from-a-multivalue-hashmap)

Comment: the problem is that jsoup.data only accepts key-> value.and I do not know how to add them.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about how HashMap works before posting a question here.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

HashMap stores a key-value pair.
So if you put a key again, it will simply update the value.

If you do this:

```
postData.put("K1",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K1",  "BBBBB");
postData.put("K1",  "CCCCC");
postData.put("K2",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K3",  "AAAAA");
```

you end up with:

```
"K1" =>  "CCCCC"
"K2" =>  "AAAAA"
"K3" =>  "AAAAA"
```

Comment: the problem is that jsoup.data only accepts key-> value.and I do not know how to add them.Thanks

Comment: Not aware of how jsoup works, does it serialize the map before sending the data out?

Answer (score 0):

The essence of a Map is that your keys are unique. There is no such thing has having multiple values for the same key.

In other words: you either have to send multiple times, or you have to have a `Map<String, List<String>>` for example. In other words: a "flat" map isn't the appropriate data structure to handle situations where you have multiple values for the same key!

Given the comment from the OP, the *other* solution could be to use a `List<Pair<String, String>>`. Meaning: it seems you mainly care to transmit mappings "A -> B" somehow. Then you can't use a map, you should rather use a list that contains such mappings!

Comment: the problem is that jsoup.data only accepts key-> value.and I do not know how to add them.Thanks

Comment: @javichu Then it really depends on what you want to do on that "jsoup" side. What is the effect you want to achieve in the end. Beyond that, see the changes I made to my answer. And just for the record: please dont forget about accepting an answer, once you get one that answers the question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

HashMap in Java Collections doesn't allow duplicates however you can use Apache's Common Collection 'MultiMap'

> Code:

```
MultiMap<String, String> postData= new MultiValueMap<>();
postData.put("K1",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K1",  "BBBBB");
postData.put("K1",  "CCCCC");
postData.put("K2",  "AAAAA");
postData.put("K3",  "AAAAA");


jsoup.connect
........
.data(postData)
....
```

To use apache common collection add following dependency in pom.xml or download its jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

read further : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiValueMap.html